# Is it possible to connect 4 tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

Is it possible to have one single SQL statement to get the data underneath?

the story: I want a list with multiple ingrediënts of multiple receipts.

**db now:**

---

**LIST**

- list_id
- list_name
- ...

---

**lIST_LINE (connectiontable to receipt)**

- list_id
- receipt_id

---

**RECEIPT**

- receipt_id
- receipt_name
- ...

---

**RECEIPT_LINE (connectiontable to ingredient)**

- receipt_id
- ingredient_id

---

**INGREDIENT**

- ingredient_id
- ingredient_name
- ....

---

I want a complete list from all ingredients needed for all receipts in one listitem.

is this possible in 1 query or do I have to run multiple query's in php (with arrays)

Comment: super, Thanks very much!!!
I was making my query with a wrong head_table

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use multiple `INNER JOIN` statements.

```
SELECT * FROM LIST 
JOIN 
IIST_LINE
ON
IIST_LINE.list_id = LIST.list_id
JOIN 
RECEIPT
ON
IIST_LINE.receipt_id = RECEIPT.receipt_id
JOIN
RECEIPT_LINE
ON
RECEIPT_LINE.receipt_id = RECEPT.receipt_id
JOIN
INGREDIENT
ON
INGREDIENT.ingredient_id = RECEIPT_LINE.ingredient_id
```

Then add a `SORT BY` for the specific columns you would like to sort by (like receipt_line)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can join but you should have relation on every table as you have now:

```
SELECT *
FROM list l
INNER JOIN list_line ll ON ll.list_id = l.list_id
INNER JOIN receipt r ON r.receipt_it = ll.receipt_id
INNER JOIN receipt_line rl ON rl.receipt_id = r.receipt_id
INNER JOIN ingredient i ON i.ingredient_id = rl. ingredient_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can:

```
 SELECT ll.list_id,i.ingredient_id,i.ingredient_name,r.receipt_id,r.receipt_name
 FROM list_line ll
 INNER JOIN receipt r ON r.receipt_id = ll.receipt_id
 INNER JOIN receipt_line rl ON rl.receipt_id = r.receipt_id
 INNER JOIN ingredient i ON i.ingredient_id = rl. ingredient_id
```

If you don't want to print list_name then first table(List) is not required hence I opt it out.

Comment: If it's helpful than an up vote will be appreciated!!